# AngularJS from array of objects to array of functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, angular-http

I've got an array of angularjs `$http` config objects:

```
    var steps= [
    {url:"http://api.com/test1", method: "GET"},
    {url:"http://api.com/test2",method: "POST"},
    {url:"http://api.com/test3",method: "GET"},
 ]
```

These are all *API* calls I need to execute in sequence. The number of this calls can vary.

I would like transform each of this object in a function executing the `$http` call (so then I can use that with `map` to obtain an array of functions).

Something like:

```
function transform(conf){
   return $http(conf);
}
```

But this, obviously, executes the `$http` call.

Comment: `execute in sequence` and using `$q.all` - not clear on this aspect. Do you want to send calls in parallel or in sequence?

Comment: I want to execute the calls in sequence

Comment: You can do `let transform = (conf) => () => $http(conf);` to get a function that returns a promise, which you can execute later. But it's still unclear what you want to do after that - you say you want to execute them in sequence, but you mention `q.all` which will execute them in parallel.

Comment: Edited the question, removed the reference to `$q.all()` that was wrong.

Comment: you just made my day... `return new Function('$http', 'return $http(config)');`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to chain the promises.

```
let promise =  steps.reduce((promise, step) => promise.then(() => $http(step)), $q());
```

**ES5**

```
let promise =  steps.reduce(function(promise, step){
     return promise.then(function(){
        return $http(step);
    });
}, $q());
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the async/await pattern where you can await in the loop of request which would make them execute in a sequence.

Try it like this

```
app.controller('yourControllerController', 
    async function($scope, $http) {

    var steps = 
    [
        { url:"http://api.com/test1", method: "GET" },
        { url:"http://api.com/test2", method: "POST" },
        { url:"http://api.com/test3", method: "GET" },
     ];

    async function processHttpRequests(){
        for(const step of steps){
            var result = await $http({ method: step.method, url: step.url});
            console.log('Url:' step.url + ' Result: ' + result);
        }
    }; 

    await processHttpRequests();
});
```

Comment: `for..in` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Ok, please teach me why :) according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787 it does what I want it to

Comment: You are looking for `for..of`, `step` in your code will be the key ('0', '1', etc) and not the element itself. In general, `for..in` should be avoided in modern code.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Thank u so much, Now I see the issue :) edited the asnwer

Comment: Does this work in AngularJS, where the promises aren’t native but come from the `$q` service?